Topologies of pairs and closed, convex sets
The present question is a simple perturbation of this one. In fact, I've just removed some adjectives from the question as asked there.
It is known, that if two locally convex topologies on a vector space determine the same collection of continuous linear functionals, then the classes of closed convex sets are the same.

I am wondering about the converse of this statement.

In particular I am interested if the following holds. Let $E$ and $F$ be vector spaces in duality, and let $H\subset F$ be such that the class of closed convex sets with respect to $\sigma(E,H)$ is the same as with respect to $\sigma(E,F)$.

What can be said about $H$? Is it true that $H=F$?


This is true. Indeed, recall that a linear functional on a locally convex space is continuous iff its kernel is closed. Thus, if the two topologies have the same collection of closed convex sets, then $\varphi$ is continuous w.r.t. the first topology iff $\ker(\varphi)$ is closed w.r.t. the first topology iff $\ker(\varphi)$ is closed w.r.t. the second topology iff $\varphi$ is continuous w.r.t. the second topology. That is, the two topologies have the same collection of continuous linear functionals.

Great, David! Thanks. I didn't remember this fact about the kernels, although they would indeed be natural convex sets to consider.

@JonBannon I first learned this fact from appendix of Murphy's "$C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory". The proof is not too bad. If $\varphi$ is nonzero and $\ker(\varphi)$ is closed, then the affine hyperplane $\varphi = 1$ is closed as well, so there are some seminorms $p_1, \cdots, p_n$ generating the topology and $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\max_i p_i(x) < \epsilon$ implies $\varphi(x) \neq 1$. From there it is not hard to see that we must have $\max_i p_i(x) < \epsilon$ implies $|\varphi(x)| < 1$ so $|\varphi(x)| \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \max_i p_i(x)$ for all $x$ and $\varphi$ is continuous.

That linear functionals with closed kernel are continuous (in topological vector spaces) is also in Rudin's Functional Analysis, Theorem 1.18.

@Jochen: This was very clearly going to be standard fare, but it was so close to the question I modified that I was surprised not to find it answered either in the body of that question or somewhere else on MSE...especially since this one is true, but the associated bounded version from the other question is false. (I probably should have not been lazy and either thought about it a bit more, or opened a book...but it may be nice to have this here...)
